# 16.04 - Wireless mouse not working

Tags: mouse

I just bought a new laptop (it's Asus Zenbook UX410UA) and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Unfortunately, I can't make my wireless mouse (Hama Roma) work. When I plug it in, nothing happens. I Google a little, I got this output from `dmesg`

```
[  542.308295] usb 1-2: new low-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  542.308773] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  542.518160] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  542.726434] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 16, error -71
```

But I can't find any solution to this. Any suggestions? Tried all the USB ports, mouse does work on another laptop.

Comment: I found [this](https://paulphilippov.com/articles/how-to-fix-device-not-accepting-address-error): "Most probably it’s a result of hardware failure rather than a driver or kernel bug. USB has an over-current protection, which gets triggered when power consumption from the port is too high. Unplug all USB devices from PC, turn power off, and wait a minute or two. Plug everything back and boot into Linux."

Comment: I found that too. Did not help. Other USB devices work, like USB flash drive. Even a different wireless mouse works.